# Asynctask speed vs same process in ExecutorService

Tags: android, android-asynctask, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

My app is required to scan a subnet for responding devices (and check port 80/8080 for a specific service).  I was using an executorservice/threadpool to complete the scan task - which took approx 30 seconds to complete.

I rewrote the above process to use an asynctask - the process now takes much longer (many minutes).

I've gone back to the original executorservice and wrapped this whole process in an asynctask as a compromise (so it doesn't block the UI and completes quickly) but doubt this is best practice.  It also creates issues with progress updates, cancelling etc.

Is it best that I go with the slower process, that provides UI updates/cancellable facility or (as the whole process only takes 30s) - go with the faster, executorservice?

Thanks.

Comment: All you need to do is adjust the priority, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14217816/1856738).

Comment: Also bear in mind that `AsyncTask`, when used with `execute()`, is serialized on Android 3.2+ devices if your `android:targetSdkVersion` is set to 13 or higher. You have to specifically use `executeOnExecutor()` and opt into the multiple-thread `AsyncTask` thread pool.

Comment: It turns out my issue wasn't with the priority of the asynctask, more that it was running sequentially.  I'm now experimenting with executeOnExecutor and handling queuing tasks (as I have 255 to run).  I've tried using executeOnExecutor on my Executor but it is still partially blocking the UI.