# How to initialize handlers from separated threads?

Tags: android, handler

I am coding an application where a remote service has to run at all time and to perform these taks :

- Create and keep a bluetooth connection to another device
- Ask this device for informations periodically (1 second)
- Get GPS Location periodically (1 second)
- Write previous datas in a text file every 1 second

For this, I created from my remote service 2 Threads : one for the data request (loopThread) and one for the GPS Location (gpsThread). The loopThread, after getting the datas from the blueTooth Device should ask the gpsThread for the location. It has to be very quick, that's why I am using a Thread, so i can store the Location in a variable which can be sent.

The remote serviceand the 2 threads should communicate through handlers.

The problem is : I can make each Handlers communicate with the remote service, but not with each other.

I create Threads like this :

```
myGPSThread = new GPSThread(mainServiceHandler,locationManager);
myLoopThread = new AcquisitionThread(mainServiceHandler, sockIn, sockOut);
```

I tried sending the Handler of one to the other by message, but Handlers seem not to be parcelable.

Does anyone have the solution to this?

Comment: Both threads together make up the service, right? And do they run in the same process? If not, why? If they do, why do you have to parcel the handler?

Comment: Both threads are created from the service, so I guess they run in the same process
If I understand your comment, I should be able to send messages to one Handler to the other right? For now, I can send message from loopThread to gpsThread, because I created gpsThread first and gave his handler as paramter to loopThread (not in my post, I did it after). But I didn't do it for gpsThread (because loopThread does not exist when I create gpsThread).
I need to be able to send messages from one to the other, both directions

Comment: Yes, same process. -- If you do not start your Threads upon creating them, you can create two Threads, then two Handlers, then call set methods for the Handlers on the Threads and finally start both Threads. But I'm not sure I'd use two Handlers in this case. I'd probably use two [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)s which have the advantage that they can be created _before_ the Threads are created.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand how to create the Handlers before creating the Threads, provided I create Handlers _in_ the Thread
`private Handler myThreadHandler = new Handler() {`
  `public void handleMessage(Message msg) {`
   `if (msg.what == ...) {do things}`
  `}`
 `};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to your `Handler` based approach, you can set up your two `Thread`s as follows.

For your `Thread`s, subclass [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) instead of Thread. Also, make them implement `Handler.Callback` and don't `start()` them right away.

```
final class GPSThread extends HandlerThread implements Handler.Callback {
    private Handler otherThreadHandler;
    public void setOtherThreadHandler(Handler otherThreadHandler) {
        this.otherThreadHandler = otherThreadHandler;
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // like in your comment
    }

}

myGPSThread  = new GPSThread(locationManager);
myLoopThread = new AcquisitionThread(sockIn, sockOut);
myGPSThreadHandler  = new Handler(myGPSThread.getLooper(), myGPSThread);
myLoopThreadHandler = new Handler(myLoopThread.getLooper(), myLoopThread);
myGPSThread.setOtherThreadHandler(myLoopThreadHandler);
myLoopThread.setOtherThreadHandler(myGPSThreadHanlder);
myGPSThread.start();
myLoopThread.start();
```

If you want low latency and your event-driven code is short and friendly, you may want to create the `HandlerThread`s with a better-than-default priority; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217816/1856738).

As already mentioned, you can as well set up two "ordinary" `Thread`s which operate on two [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)s; these Threads would block in their `run()` methods upon waiting for a message (aka Object) from the other Thread.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but after a short reflexion, I could have to start both threads separately (maybe the GPSThread in the onCreate, while the loopThread would be started on action of the user).
I guess it is definitely not practical to use 2 threads in my case, so i'll make a GPS Service instead of a GPSThread.
Your answer, however, could be useful to other people, as I didn't find a lot of information on this precise case, that's why I'll accept it, to close the post

Comment: Thank you. I'm really not sure what the right design for your case is because it depends on when to start what and how it is supposed to interact. Either way, good luck!

Comment: To tell the truth, for the moment, I am trying to code a first app, which will help me with the global one. It's really difficult to explain the global project concisely, that's why I explain only a part. Moreover, the real project changes in function of the way I communicate with the BlueToothDevice. And at last, I have to keep in mind that this app will evolve. So you see, it's not very simple! Thanks for your help anyway!