# Changing the image of the ImageButton when the onClick is called

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an ImageButton which performs an long running operation when clicked. So what I am unsuccessfully trying to do is change the image at the beginning of the *onClick* call and change it back at the end.

I have tried the below code but what I found is android redraws the button image after the *onClick* is finished so it's no use.

I am also open to other ways to do this if possible.

Below is the code piece I use. *Thread.sleep* represents the long running operation. I would like to see the image change when the execution reaches the sleep not after the *onClick* is finished.

```
btnTest = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
btnTest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println("start");
    btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

    System.out.println("end");
    btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.del);
}
});
```

Comment: so what is it you wanted?? Change the `ImageButton` bg when user presses the button and take it back when he/she releases the touch??

Comment: you can implement on touch listener for key down ( user pressed button ) and on key up (user realeased button )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you `sleep()` on (or otherwise block) the UI thread. Please understand that the main/UI thread is responsible for redraws and all event handling. If you *sleep* there (`onClick()` is executed ion the UI thread), then Android will be unable to do *anything* user interface related.

The background is that a multithreaded GUI would be extremely inefficient. Most UI related calls, such as `setBackground`, simply set some data or even schedule some more activities, have no immediate effect and will only yield results if the control returns to the main UI thread control loop, e.g. for a coordinated redraw. Just imagine what would happen if you launched a couple of layout changes one after another and each one would be processed immediately -- that would result in a huge number of computations which would become invalid right the next moment.

So the main thread is nothing but a huge loop processing all kinds of callbacks, including `Activity` lifecycle methods, event listener callbacks etc. So the UI is single threaded if you will.

What you need to do is perform your long-running operation on an `AsyncTask` or Thread. For starters, I'd try an `AsyncTask`. In the AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()` method, which is run on the UI thread again, you can manipulate your user interface as you wish.

For a quick success, you can also use a Thread:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // on UI thread
    btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
    // launch concurrent thread
    (new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            // the code of this method will run concurrently
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("start");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                System.out.println("end");
                // at this point, we need to get back to the UI thread
                // for simplicity, we use the view's convenience method for that
                v.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    // the code of this method will run on the UI thread
                    public void run() {
                       btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.del);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    ).start();
}
```

`AsyncTask` looks much nicer but it's not easily created and used on-the-fly.

Please note that the code above creates a `Thread` which will run until either it leaves its `run()` method, or Android kills the Linux process which hosts your app.

Also note that this Thread holds references to a lot of objects from your code, because it can access everything from its surrounding scope.

The conclusion is, that if your Thread does run for a long time, it could hold references to a View which is not even visible anymore, so zombie memory objects could worsen the resource consumption of your app.

Also, you mentioned that you're doing a long-running operation there. The question is, does that operation *wait* or does it *compute* something. If it computes something, you may find that it now takes ten times longer unless you [adjust the `AsyncTask`/`Thread` priority as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217816/1856738).

Comment: Thanks, well explained and helpful

Comment: @JohnBale Thank you. Glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you will be doing some operation in onclick instead of just Thread.Sleep().

In that case you could use the following approach using AsyncTask.

```
btnTest = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
btnTest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

       new SomeLongRunningOperationAsyncTask().execute();

   }
});
```

> **AsyncTask class for the long running process.**

```
class SomeLongRunningOperationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("start");
        btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //your long running operation.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("end");
        btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.del);
    }
}
```